# PIP Failed to build wheel (rtmidi)

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to pip install rtmidi, but the wheel keeps failing.

Here is the error that I get:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\ιτ\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ΙΤ\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9ya53ebd\\rtmidi\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ΙΤ\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9ya53ebd\\rtmidi\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\ΙΤ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-lkqfq8uh'
       cwd: C:\Users\ΙΤ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9ya53ebd\rtmidi\
  Complete output (39 lines):
  c:\users\ιτ\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\extension.py:131: UserWarning: Unknown Extension options: 'headers'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\rtmidi
  copying rtmidi\collector.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\rtmidi
  copying rtmidi\randomout.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\rtmidi
  copying rtmidi\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\rtmidi
  running build_ext
  building 'rtmidi._rtmidi' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\cpp_src
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -D__WINDOWS_MM__= -DPK_WINDOWS=1 -Ic:\users\ιτ\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include -Ic:\users\ιτ\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpcpp_src\RtMidi.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\cpp_src\RtMidi.obj /EHsc
  RtMidi.cpp
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -D__WINDOWS_MM__= -DPK_WINDOWS=1 -Ic:\users\ιτ\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include -Ic:\users\ιτ\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpcpp_src\MidiMessage.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\cpp_src\MidiMessage.obj /EHsc
  MidiMessage.cpp
  cpp_src\MidiMessage.cpp(1055): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
  cpp_src\MidiMessage.cpp(1057): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -D__WINDOWS_MM__= -DPK_WINDOWS=1 -Ic:\users\ιτ\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include -Ic:\users\ιτ\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpcpp_src\PyMidiMessage.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\cpp_src\PyMidiMessage.obj /EHsc
  PyMidiMessage.cpp
  cpp_src\PyMidiMessage.cpp(72): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  cpp_src\PyMidiMessage.cpp(87): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -D__WINDOWS_MM__= -DPK_WINDOWS=1 -Ic:\users\ιτ\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include -Ic:\users\ιτ\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpcpp_src\rtmidimodule.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\cpp_src\rtmidimodule.obj /EHsc
  rtmidimodule.cpp
  cpp_src\rtmidimodule.cpp(50): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
  cpp_src\rtmidimodule.cpp(52): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
  cpp_src\rtmidimodule.cpp(54): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
  cpp_src\rtmidimodule.cpp(56): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
  cpp_src\rtmidimodule.cpp(58): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
  cpp_src\rtmidimodule.cpp(60): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
  cpp_src\rtmidimodule.cpp(62): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
  cpp_src\rtmidimodule.cpp(64): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows♂  7.1\Lib" /LIBPATH:c:\users\ιτ\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\ιτ\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\ATLMFC\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64" winmm.lib python34.lib /EXPORT:PyInit__rtmidi build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\cpp_src\RtMidi.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\cpp_src\MidiMessage.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\cpp_src\PyMidiMessage.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\cpp_src\rtmidimodule.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\rtmidi\_rtmidi.cp38-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\cpp_src\_rtmidi.cp38-win_amd64.lib
  LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'python34.lib'
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.25.28610\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1181
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for rtmidi
```

And:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\ιτ\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ΙΤ\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9ya53ebd\\rtmidi\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ΙΤ\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9ya53ebd\\rtmidi\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ΙΤ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ezood9b7\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\ιτ\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\rtmidi'
         cwd: C:\Users\ΙΤ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9ya53ebd\rtmidi\
    Complete output (39 lines):
    c:\users\ιτ\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\extension.py:131: UserWarning: Unknown Extension options: 'headers'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\rtmidi
    copying rtmidi\collector.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\rtmidi
    copying rtmidi\randomout.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\rtmidi
    copying rtmidi\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\rtmidi
    running build_ext
    building 'rtmidi._rtmidi' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\cpp_src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -D__WINDOWS_MM__= -DPK_WINDOWS=1 -Ic:\users\ιτ\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include -Ic:\users\ιτ\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpcpp_src\RtMidi.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\cpp_src\RtMidi.obj /EHsc
    RtMidi.cpp
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -D__WINDOWS_MM__= -DPK_WINDOWS=1 -Ic:\users\ιτ\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include -Ic:\users\ιτ\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpcpp_src\MidiMessage.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\cpp_src\MidiMessage.obj /EHsc
    MidiMessage.cpp
    cpp_src\MidiMessage.cpp(1055): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
    cpp_src\MidiMessage.cpp(1057): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -D__WINDOWS_MM__= -DPK_WINDOWS=1 -Ic:\users\ιτ\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include -Ic:\users\ιτ\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpcpp_src\PyMidiMessage.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\cpp_src\PyMidiMessage.obj /EHsc
    PyMidiMessage.cpp
    cpp_src\PyMidiMessage.cpp(72): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    cpp_src\PyMidiMessage.cpp(87): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -D__WINDOWS_MM__= -DPK_WINDOWS=1 -Ic:\users\ιτ\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include -Ic:\users\ιτ\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpcpp_src\rtmidimodule.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\cpp_src\rtmidimodule.obj /EHsc
    rtmidimodule.cpp
    cpp_src\rtmidimodule.cpp(50): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
    cpp_src\rtmidimodule.cpp(52): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
    cpp_src\rtmidimodule.cpp(54): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
    cpp_src\rtmidimodule.cpp(56): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
    cpp_src\rtmidimodule.cpp(58): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
    cpp_src\rtmidimodule.cpp(60): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
    cpp_src\rtmidimodule.cpp(62): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
    cpp_src\rtmidimodule.cpp(64): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows♂    7.1\Lib" /LIBPATH:c:\users\ιτ\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\ιτ\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\ATLMFC\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64" winmm.lib python34.lib /EXPORT:PyInit__rtmidi build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\cpp_src\RtMidi.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\cpp_src\MidiMessage.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\cpp_src\PyMidiMessage.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\cpp_src\rtmidimodule.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\rtmidi\_rtmidi.cp38-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\cpp_src\_rtmidi.cp38-win_amd64.lib
    LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'python34.lib'
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.25.28610\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1181
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\ιτ\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ΙΤ\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9ya53ebd\\rtmidi\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ΙΤ\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9ya53ebd\\rtmidi\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ΙΤ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ezood9b7\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\ιτ\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\rtmidi' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I tried installing wheel and reinstalling python 64bit. The same error also occurs when I try to install any other package via wheel.

- Python version: 3.8 OS:
- Windows 10
- CPU: Intel Core i7

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in `setup.py`, in the following code:

```
elif OSNAME == 'Windows':
    define_macros = [('__WINDOWS_MM__', ''),
                     ('PK_WINDOWS', '1')]
    library_dirs = ['C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib']
    libraries = ['winmm', 'python34']
```

It seems the code is intended to work only with Python 3.4. Also

```
  classifiers=['Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
               'Intended Audience :: Developers',
               'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
               'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
               ]
```

Try to download the source, extract the archive, edit `setup.py`, and recompile.

Comment: What should I change in the setup.py. and which source code should I download? Thanks.

Comment: The source code of `rtmidi`. At least change `'python34'` to `'python38'`.